# What regex to use to take only first occurrence of number in string?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have table with comments like this

```
'Payment amount: 11000,50 from 144232'

'Payment amount: 13 450,20 from 144232'
```

Sometimes white spaces occurs in number, because people typing this manually. I need to get first numbers like **11000,50** and **13 450,20** from example.

I'm trying to use
`regexp_replace('Payment amount: 11000,20 from 144232','([a-zA-Z:\s])','','g')` and get result `'11000,20144232'`, but I need only '11000,00'

How can I improve regex or what function I need to use to get this numbers?

Comment: you want to extract only that value?

Comment: I need to get first number with two numbers after comma

Answer (score 1):

To get the first number in the string with a comma and 2 digits after it, and spaces can occur between the digits due to typing:

```
^[a-zA-Z:\s]*(\d[\s\d]*,\s*\d\s*\d)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z:\s]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed chars in the character class
- `(` Capture **group 1** (this will contain the value)

  - `\d` Match a digit
  - `\d[\s\d]*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char or digit
  - `,\s*\d\s*\d` Match a comma and 2 digits with optional whitespace chars (Add `\M` if there can be no more word character following)
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQaxEp/1) | [Postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/NEIG1241)

---

A broader match could be to match 0+ times any char except a digit `\D*` instead of using `[a-zA-Z:\s]*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GK7TPb/1)

Answer (score 0):

This works for your examples, with or without decimals:

```
^[a-zA-Z:\s]+([\d\s]*(,\d{1,2})?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/1JEe3F/1

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT (regexp_match(
           'Payment amount: 11000,00 from 144232',
           '[[:digit:]][[:digit:] ]*(?:,[[:digit:]]+)')
       )[1];

 regexp_match 
--------------
 11000,00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Sometimes happens that 1st value like '11 000,00' with whitespace between 
hundredths. How can I solve this case?

Comment: I changed the expression to cover that. But don't expect any expression like that to magically always do the right thing with arbitrary data.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler but less strict, `([+\-]?\d[\d ,\.]+).*`

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Payment amount: 11,000.00 from 144232', '([+\-]?\d[\d ,\.]+).*'))[1];
```

Result: 11,000.00